# Animation loop in less is not working

Tags: animation, less

I'm trying to generate this:

```
@keyframes move {

0% { transform: translateY(12.6362937434469px)}
1% { transform: translateY(17.0398631884564px)}
2% { transform: translateY(26.8988457853083px)}
3% { transform: translateY(40.3725348537822px)}
4% { transform: translateY(55.3796708482273px)}
5% { transform: translateY(69.8839929760395px)}
6% { transform: translateY(82.1419149981669px)}
7% { transform: translateY(90.8858638077591px)}
8% { transform: translateY(95.4277979071359px)}
9% { transform: translateY(95.6790818947141px)}
10% { transform: translateY(92.0937083365851px)}
```

}

But I'm not sure how to do it in less (putting that 'px' in the end and everything).

I've tried:

```
@keyframes move { 
    .loop (@index) when (@index <100) {
        .loop (@index + 1);
        @index*1% {transform: translateY(@index*1px)}
    }
}

#dots {
    fill: orange;
    animation: move 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Could really appreciate help, I keep bouncing into different syntaxes of less and none seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried? So far your Q looks like "write the code for me".

Comment: @seven-phases-max, I've updated my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Better! You're almost there. Your loop mixin *definition* is almost correct and the only thing missing is the *call* of that mixin. See http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature ("launch the loop" line in particular).

Comment: (Not counting though that *100 steps* of linear move do not make much sense).

Comment: Additionally note that `@index*1%` expression cannot be used as a frame identifier (neither keyframe ids nor selectors may have arbitrary expressions, only [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) could be used there).

Comment: So in summary your code would look something [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%40keyframes%20move%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop()%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.loop(%40index%3A%200)%20when%20(%40index%20%3C%2011)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40name%3A%20%40index%20*%2010%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40%7Bname%7D%20%7Btransform%3A%20translateY(%40index%20*%2010px)%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.loop(%40index%20%2B%201)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D) in the end.

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max, everything seems to be working fine.